# Django Rest Api - display the username for every user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have a model called 'Task' and the task has 'UserProfile's working on them. These 'UserProfile' models are just normal Users but inside the App of the 'Task'.

This is the API I have right now:

```
"tasks": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Läs På Internet",
            "description": "asdasdasdasa",
            "created": "2019-06-08",
            "deadline": "2019-06-19",
            "state": "new",
            "stickers": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Detta är en sticker",
                    "content": "Sillicon Valley",
                    "created": "2019-06-08",
                    "creator": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "user": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "checkmarks": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Googla",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ],
            "workers": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "user": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Läs i böcker",
            "description": "aaa",
            "created": "2019-06-10",
            "deadline": "2019-06-25",
            "state": "done",
            "stickers": [],
            "checkmarks": [],
            "workers": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "user": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

As you can see every user now just has 'id' and 'user', which are both the ID. How do I get the `username` for every user and display them in the rest api?

```
# Users
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'All Users'

  def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
 def create_user_data(sender, update_fields, created, instance, **kwargs):
if created:
    user  = instance
    profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)


#Tasks
class Task(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
  created = models.DateField(default=date.today)
  deadline = models.DateField(default=date.today)
  state = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='new')
  stickers = models.ManyToManyField(Sticker, blank=True)
  checkmarks = models.ManyToManyField(Checkmark, blank=True)
  workers = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, related_name='TaskWorkers')

 class Meta:
     verbose_name_plural = 'Tasks'

 def __str__(self):
    return "{name}".format(name=self.name)
```

serializers:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('id', 'user')

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  stickers = StickerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
  checkmarks = CheckmarkSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
  workers = UserProfileSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
  class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'created', 'deadline', 'state', 'stickers', 'checkmarks', 'workers')
```

views:

```
class TaskView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
  queryset = Task.objects.all()
  serializer_class = TaskSerializer

class UserTaskView(TaskView):
  def get_queryset(self):
    return Task.objects.filter(workers__user=self.request.user)
```

The User Views are for displaying only for the users that are assigned!

Answer (score 1):

You can either update the `user` serializer inside your `UserProfileSerializer` with something like this (creating a serializer with the fields you want for the `User`):

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  user = UserSerializer()
  class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('id', 'user')
```

or this (accessing user fields from within the `UserProfileSerializer`):

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
  class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('id', 'user', 'username')
```

Answer (score -1):

As documented below in 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations
You can get the user profile details inside the tasks as:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  ......
 user = UserSerializer()
 class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields = (...., 'user',....., 'workers')
```

This will return all the fields in the the user model as part of the task nested json

Comment: his `Task` model is related to users through the `UserProfile` model, not the `User` one - he won't be able to access `user` directly from within a `Task` instance.